# Editing JSON - Add Attribute

Tags: json, attributes, addition

I have a slew of JSON files I'm getting dumps of, with data from the day/period it was pulled. Most of the JSON files I'm dealing with are a lot larger than this, but I figured a smaller one would be easier to work with.

```
{"playlists":[{"uri":"spotify:user:11130196075:playlist:1Ov4b3NkyzIMwfY9E8ixpE","listeners":366,"streams":386,"dateAdded":"2016-02-24","newListeners":327,"title":"#Covers","owner":"Saga Prommeedet"},{"uri":"spotify:user:mickeyrose30:playlist:2Ov4b3NkyzIMwfY9E8ixpE","listeners":229,"streams":263,"dateAdded":"removed","newListeners":154,"title":"bestcovers2016","owner":"Mickey Rose"}],"top":2,"total":53820}
```

What I'm essentially trying to do is add a date attribute to each line of data, so that when I combine multiple JSON files to put through an analytical tool, the right row of data is associated with the correct date. My first thought was to write it as such:

```
{"playlists":[{"uri":"spotify:user:11130196075:playlist:1Ov4b3NkyzIMwfY9E8ixpE","listeners":366,"streams":386,"dateAdded":"2016-02-24","newListeners":327,"title":"#Covers","owner":"Saga Prommeedet"},{"uri":"spotify:user:mickeyrose30:playlist:2Ov4b3NkyzIMwfY9E8ixpE","listeners":229,"streams":263,"dateAdded":"removed","newListeners":154,"title":"bestcovers2016","owner":"Mickey Rose"}],"top":2,"total":53820,"date":072617}
```

since the "top" and "total" attributes are showing up on each row of data (with the associated values also showing up on each row) when I put it through an analytical tool like Tableau.

Also, have been editing and saving files through Brackets, and testing things through this converter (https://konklone.io/json/)

Comment: What is your programming language?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript language

```
var m = JSON.parse(json_string);
m["date"]="20170804";
JSON.stringify(m);
```

This will work for you, very simple,